GTK+3 round button
how can I make the button perfectly round? This is my css:
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, “#font_button {min-width:5px;min-height:5px;border-radius: 50%;background: white;}”, -1, NULL);
gtk_widget_set_name(img_struct->sub_color , “font_button”);

the flags in gtk_box_pack_start() are both set to false and even by using the circular class the button is not perfectly round as you can see in the screenshot.


Because the circle's width != height?

How do I set them? If I use the keywords width and height I get a gtk message in the terminal stating they are not supported.

Thanks to Emmanuele Bassi from discourse.gnome.org this is the solution:
gtk_widget_set_valign(button, GTK_ALIGN_CENTER);

